# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server 'MongoNetworkError'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ac-uw3j72u-shard-00-02.27017] on first connect [Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)name:'MongoNetworkError'
Found Solutions
1.If it comes do check ip address/ Search my ip address in your system/laptop it will show your internet connected ip address add that in go to network access add you ip address there.
2.Then check it local mongodb connection.
3.cheack mongodb url link, username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working and another method is install mongodb compass in local and try running server using localhost 27017 then u can go for online